# The yet adverb and its meaning

Tags: meaning

I was a little confused by the meaning of the adverb in here:

> And **yet** he hesitated before taking his first step toward his destiny.

I expected *still* instead of *yet* in that sentence. Does it have the same meaning here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Still](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/still_1) and [yet](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/yet_2) have several meanings, but both can be used in your example to convey the same thought. Consider LDOCE definition for yet as a conjunction:

> used to introduce a fact, situation, or quality that is surprising after what you have just said

and LDOCE definition 2 for still:

> in spite of what has just been said or done

So I would understand the given example like this: based on something you previously told us about him we would expect him to take his first step toward his destiny without hesitation, but to our surprise, he hesitated (for some reason).

Comment: These are similar thoughts, but I wouldn't call them "the same." There's a slight difference, and I don't think they're quite interchangeable.

Comment: {Be that as it may/yet/still}, I doubt that many readers these days would catch the subtle distinction. Alas, entropy.

Comment: @Brian HItchcook Too subtle for me, I'm afraid. I've tried but I can't grasp it. Can you please help?

Comment: I was just responding to J.R. , trying to imply (with my curly braces) that I think "yet" and "still" are, for all practical purposes, in most cases, interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

> And yet he hesitated before taking his first step toward his destiny.

Here, *and yet* means *nevertheless.*

Edit:

Sorry, I just noticed your question, "expected still instead of yet in that sentence. Does it have the same meaning here?"

Not exactly.  "Still" suggests a bit of a contradiction with what came before.